# How to connect C# and PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have 2 forms, the first1 has username, password box and login button.
when I click on login button it will compares user name password in PostgresSQL.
But I got error with this line

> NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>     [ ERROR: 42P01: relation "login" does not exist ]

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool blnfound = false;
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=admin123;Database=Login");
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login WHERE name='" + tb1.Text + "' and password = '" + tb2.Text + "'",conn);
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            blnfound = true;
            Form2 f5 = new Form2();
            f5.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        if (blnfound == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name or password is incorrect", "Message Box", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Well, are you sure that you have a table named 'login' in your database?

Comment: make sure you are connecting to the right database, also try to enclose login in double quotes so the query should be `Select * From "login" .....`

Answer (score 2):

Check your DB if the table name Login is correct. By the way you need to filter your input values, because your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

You should also try changing either your table or database name, they're both called login and this might cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=admin123;**Database=Login**
```

Login is the Database Name

```
"SELECT * FROM **login** WHERE name='" + tb1.Text + "' and password = '" + tb2.Text + "'",conn
```

Login is the table name

If this is correct, then check whether the table **login**, exists in the database **LOGIN**.

```
ERROR: 42P01: relation "login" does not exist
```

**Relation**  means **Table**

Also, you cannot use table names starting with Upper Case in Postgres. If you have a table name starting with Uppercase, then you need to enclose it within double quotes.

Comment: I was thinking case-sensitivity too.

Comment: Postgres will actually make everything lowercase, unless it's put in quotes.

Comment: @MikeChristensen If the table was created as `"Login"` with double quotes then it will always be necessary to invoke it that way.

Comment: That last paragraph it wrong. You can use table names starting with Upper Case in Postgresql and invoke them however you like (upper and lowercase) as long as they are not created with the name inside double quotes.